# Overrides vs Variables Files in Semantic-UI

Tags: html, css, less, semantic-ui

I'm a newbie and would like to ask the difference between overrides and variables in semantic-ui? For example what is the difference between site.overrides and site.variables?

Comment: [Theming](http://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html). In short: `site.overrides` usually contains just CSS code and `site.variables` only a preprocessor variables.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Dude. You should write tech manuals, save us all a lot of time. And post this as an answer so I can vote the hell out of it.